# Compiling Starling using Flash IDE instead of Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder, starling-framework

Almost all applications I build are design heavy so it makes sense for me to compile using the Flash IDE.
However, most Starling demos I've seen require the creation of Texture objects using embedded png's and are compiled in Flash Builder.
Is there any reason I couldn't (or shouldn't) use the Flash IDE for compiling Stage3d (Starling) projects?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no reasons you shouldn't use Flash IDE for building Stage3d applications (except that Flash IDE is extremely inconvenient for working with complex projects, but it's just my opinion).

And yes, you won't be able to embed assets using [Embed] meta-tag. But in fact this is not required - it's just the simplest way to do this. You can load assets from external files (and it's a preferred way as it reduces RAM consumption, see mobile Starling application example). Or you can make use of Flash Library (of course, for each asset you should check "Export for ActionScript" option and assign unique class name in the Properties dialog).

However, I think that use of Flash IDE in compiling design-heavy applications won't simplify your work, because you'll anyway have to collect all of your textures into single atlas (or several atlases). And there is no big difference between obtaining an atlas (which is just an image, as GPU doesn't support vector textures) from Library or loading it from external file. Personally, I use Flash IDE to make assets and IntelliJ IDEA to write, build and debug the code.